# passing a List that is a class generates error, List that is string does not

Tags: c#, list, xamarin.ios

I am having an issue passing a List to a class constructor as it generates a compile error:

> Cannot convert `System.Collections.Generic.List<CupuleAdmin.RoomViewController.Rooms>` expression to type `System.Collections.Generic.List<CupuleAdmin.TableSource.Rooms>`

```
protected List<Rooms> tableList = new List<Rooms>();

public TableSource (List<Rooms> table)
{
    tableList = table;

}
public class Rooms
{

    public int id {get;set;}
    public int room {get;set;}
    public string desc {get;set;}

}
```

I populated the list in another class
      public class RoomViewController : UIViewController {

```
 //.....
    class Rooms
    {
        [PrimaryKey]
        public int id {get;set;}
        public int room {get;set;}
        public string desc {get;set;}

    }     

         var db = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath); 
         var allrooms = db.Query("select * from rooms");
```

}

and then attempt to pass the List to the other class's constructor

```
var table = new UITableView(View.Bounds);

table.Source = new TableSource(allrooms);
```

But I am getting a compile error on the line above - error reports  the cannot convert `System.Collections.Generic.List` expression to type `System.Collections.Generic.List` issue.

if I change the List to a type string the class compiles ok.

In all cases in both classes where the custom `List<Rooms>` is referenced it shows in my IDE as of the proper type : `List<Rooms>`

Is there something special I need to be doing when passing a List that contains an object/class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty obvious what's going on here, everything you need to know is in your error message. You have 2 different declarations for the `Rooms` class, one in your `RoomViewController` and the other in your `TableSource` and appear to be leaking them across your classes.

You need to make sure you are passing the *expected* type into the `TableSource` class. To elaborate further, your `TableSource` constructor looks like:

```
public TableSource(List<CupuleAdmin.TableSource.Rooms> table)
{
}
```

And you are trying to pass:

```
List<CupuleAdmin.RoomViewController.Rooms> allrooms = new List<...>();
table.Source = new TableSource(allrooms);
```

Comment: Thank James, was the answer, fixed

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to pass the right `Type`.

CupuleAdmin.**RoomViewController**.Rooms?

OR

CupuleAdmin.**TableSource**.Rooms?

Comment: Thank you very much, that was very much my problem - fixed!. James thank you also, was correct too. Also sorry i marked yours as the correct response first, but then realized James was first.